# Paraphrase these sentences

Tags: paraphrasing

I would like to paraphrase the following paragraph:

The family is considered the most influential single agency of socialization for the following reasons :

- Is that it has the main responsibility for socializing children in the crucial early years of life.
- Is that the family is located somewhere in the social structure.

My attempts:

The family is considered the most influential single agency of socialization for the following reasons :

- It has the major responsibility for socializing children in the first decisive years
- It lies somewhere in the social structure

Could someone correct me or help me to paraphrase it.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Paraphrase*** : express the meaning of (something written or spoken) using different words, especially to achieve greater clarity. (*Google Dictionary*)

You have missed the essential points of paraphrasing, which are to **use your own words** to make it **shorter** and **clearer**, keeping only the essential meaning.

Break the sentence down in parts :

- "the most influential single agency" could be replaced by "the best way" : I am assuming it is influential in a good way. This loses some of the meaning but it is short and clear.
- "socializing children in the crucial early years of life" could be replaced by "raising children."
- "located somewhere in the social structure" means "in society".

Putting this together we get

> The family is considered the best way of raising children in society.